# Getting NotificationListener in android 4.0

Tags: android, android-intent

I make a app in which I get the data from the notification by setting first this

```
  Intent intent=new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");

  startActivity(intent);
```

This code run is run good in api level 21 but when I try to run same code for api level 17 it give error

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS }.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS` and the Android `NotificationListenerService` was added in API level 18.

Reference - [NotificationListenerService API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)

Although you can't use the `NotificationListenerService` pre-API 18 [**this blog documents**](https://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/capture-toast-or-notification-using-accessibility-service/) how to capture notification events using an `AccessibilityService` (introduced in API 4), which may be of some help to you.

Comment: Sir i known that but i want to use it on api level 15 please give me some solution for it.

Comment: there is no other way. Using AccessibilityService is the best you can do